# Запрос в postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеются таблицы:

**types**: id, title-содержит большое количество расширений(png, bmp, ... итд]

**files**: id, idFolder, name, typeId

**Folders**: id, folderName

Пытаюсь запросом или запросами получить такую таблицу:

**result**: folder.id, folderName, sum(types)-выводится количество расширений имеющихся в файле, typeFiles1, typeFiles2, ... - выводятся столбцы с названием расширений и в них значения равняющиеся количеству файлов данного типа в папке

Использую postgreSQL, запускаю в pgAdmin в браузере

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | png |
| 2 | bmp |
| ... | ... |

| id | folderName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Folder1 |
| 2 | Folder2 |
| ... | ... |

| id | idFolder | typeId | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | picture1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | picture2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | picture3 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | picture4 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | picture5 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | picture6 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | picture7 |

**Итоговый результат:**

| folder.id | folder.title | К-во файлов в папке | png | bmp | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Folder1 | 5 | 2 | 3 | ... |
| 2 | Folder2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | ... |

**UDP: На данный момент получил такую таблицу:**

| idFolder | folderName | type | Количество |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Folder1 | png | 2 |
| 1 | Folder1 | bmp | 5 |
| 2 | Folder2 | png | 2 |

Как далее вынести типы в столбцы не знаю, crosstab не получается

```
CREATE TABLE public.files
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999 CACHE 1 ),
    folder_id integer,
    type_id integer,
    title character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)

CREATE TABLE public.folders
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999 CACHE 1 ),
    title character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT folders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.types
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999 CACHE 1 ),
    title character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT types_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

insert into files (folder_id, type_id, title
values (1, 1, 'picture1')
insert into files (folder_id, type_id, title)
values (1, 1, 'picture2')
insert into files (folder_id, type_id, title)
values (1, 2, 'picture3')
insert into files (folder_id, type_id, title
values (1, 2, 'picture4')
insert into files (folder_id, type_id, title)
values (1, 2, 'picture5')
insert into files (folder_id, type_id, title)
values (2, 1, 'picture6')
insert into files (folder_id, type_id, title)
values (2, 1, 'picture7')

insert into folders (title)
values ('folder1')
insert into folders (title)
values ('folder2')


insert into types (title)
values ('png')
insert into types (title)
values ('bmp')
```

Comment: Сперва всё связываете, группируете, агрегируете, а потом [CROSSTAB()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tablefunc.html).

Comment: кросстабом не понятно как пользоваться, в описании функции написано, что должно обязательно быть 3 колонки, а у меня их больше из за колонок с названием папок и файлов. Помимо этого нужно вручную прописывать будущие заголовки колонок с расширениями, а это не правильно, потому что их может быть очень большое количество и постоянно меняться

Comment: обновил, что на данный момент получается

Comment: Выложите исходные данные в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скриптов. Покажите требуемый результат для именно этих данных.

Comment: не пойму как в виде sql запросов экспортировать бд

Comment: Вот ведь... а просто руками набрать - не?

Comment: Через экспорт удобнее. Надо было мне в phpMeAdmin набросать быстренько и там одной кнопочкой экспортируется все прекрасно. sql запросы добавил. Результат находится в таблице предпоследней итоговый. Многоточия обозначают, что типов может быть больше

Comment: *Результат находится в таблице предпоследней итоговый.* Он не соответствует приведённым исходным данным.

Comment: Что там не правильно? Вижу, 4 запроса не вставилось почему то, сейчас добавлю

Comment: Добавил инсерты

Comment: Да ну нафиг. Оказывается, постгресс, насмотревшись на ms sql, тоже не умеет динамические имена в сводной таблице... ща сделаю статически.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       folders.id folder_id,
       folders.title folder_title,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY folders.id) total_count,
       SUM((types.title = 'bmp') :: INT) OVER (PARTITION BY folders.id) bmp,
       SUM((types.title = 'png') :: INT) OVER (PARTITION BY folders.id) png
FROM files
JOIN folders ON files.folder_id = folders.id
JOIN types ON files.type_id = types.id
ORDER BY 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1ad7e0d5fbb7451577223618a8bbaa8a

Comment: проблема заключается в том, что записей стобцов с типами может быть больше, автоматически не как не сделать что бы проставлялись колонки?

Comment: Тогда только разве что получать список имеющихся в папке/папках типов и динамически строить строку запроса. Ей-бо, дешевле будет получить вертикальный вывод и сделать сводную уже на клиенте, его средствами построения отчётов.

Comment: Вот тут я с Вами абсолютно согласен!!! Спасибо большое

Comment: А можно условие в select добавить, без динамического программирования, что если колонка bmp пустая не выводить ее?

Comment: @helldrg Это как раз и есть динамика. В Постгрессе структура выходного набора запроса жёстко фиксирована, и её изменение возможно только в динамике.